# Laravel Update user's data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a traveling app and the user has the possibility to edit their own departure date in case of a misplacement. At the moment, the user can edit the departure date from everyone. While it only should edit their own. Everything is working, but the update function where it should look for `Auth::user();`. Any idea how I should make this?

Here is the code:-

`DepartureController.php`

```
 public function edit(LocationUser $LocationUsers)
{
    return view('departure.edit', compact('LocationUsers'));
}

public function update(Request $request, LocationUser)
{
    $LocationUsers = Auth::user();

    $LocationUsers->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('home', $LocationUsers)
        ->withSuccess('Departure updated!');
}
```

The `web.php`

```
//Backend Departure date
Route::get('/departure/create', 'DepartureController@create')->name('departure.create');
Route::post('/departure/create', 'DepartureController@store')->name('departure.store');
Route::get('/departure/edit/{LocationUsers}', 'DepartureController@edit')->name('departure.edit{id}');
Route::patch('/departure/edit/{LocationUsers}', 'DepartureController@update')->name('departure.update');
```

The `edit.blade.php`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{$LocationUsers->departure_date}}
                    Update my departure
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
                            {{ session('success') }}
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                        <form method="post" action="{{route('departure.update', $LocationUsers)}}">
                            {!!csrf_field().method_field('patch')!!}
                        <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
                            <label class="control-label" for="departure_date"></label>
                            Date
                            <input class="form-control" id="departure_date" name="departure_date"
                                   placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update departure">
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `User model`

```
public function daysUntilDeparture()
{
    if ($this->location()->count() < 1) {
        return "No departure date has been given";
    }

    $location = $this->location[0];

    $userLocation = LocationUser::where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->where('location_id', $location->id)
        ->first();

    $departure_date = $userLocation->departure_date;
    return $departure_date->diffInDays(Carbon::now());


}
```

The `LocationUser` model

```
<?php
```

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LocationUser extends Model
{
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y';

```
protected $fillable = ['departure_date', 'user_id'];
protected $dates = ['departure_date'];
protected $table = 'location_users';

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}

public function location() {
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Location', 'id', 'location_id');
}

public function setDepartureDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['departure_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(self::DATE_FORMAT, $date);
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any model?care to share them?I would like to see it

Comment: @InnerFire Model is in the post

Comment: let me get this clear,your problem is that you dont update current users data but sb else,whats the relationship between users and the the current model you are trying to update do they have any relationship?How do you find the current user from the session or from what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $date = Carbon::parse($request->departure_date);
    $LocationUsers = LocationUser::where('user_id', Auth::id())->update(['departure_date' => $date]);

    if($LocationUsers){
        return redirect()->route('home', $LocationUsers)->withSuccess('Departure updated!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, it is still expecting a variable next to 'LocationUser'.

Comment: @Hollow-Serenity check my updated answer & let me know if it works.